# How to use nyroModal JQuery plugin in javascript redirects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, nyromodal

I'm using the nyroModal JQuery Plugin: http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/

What I want to do is I want the page which I redirect in javascript to open in modal window. If you go to the link above there is an information about the usage of the plugin. It looks simple, but I still couldn't figure it out.

And simply, the usage of the plugin is to include nyroModal function. I tried to do this, but didn't work:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.location.nyroModal()='redirect.html';
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you want to do. You click on a link which opens a new modal window with a new page loaded inside the modal window right?

Comment: No actually you don't click on a link. I've shortened the question. In fact, I am gonna use this in an AJAX form. So after many things happen in javascript code of the AJAX form, I want to redirect the page to a new page, but in a modal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.nyroModalManual({
  url: 'redirect.html'
});
```

If you want that to happen when the page loads then wrap it in a doc ready.

Comment: This will invoke a manual modal as soon as it is called. Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: A quick question: instead of redirecting to an url, may I show an html code that I want. What should I use that for that? data:'<htmlcode>' ?

Comment: I would use the DOM Element (hhidden div) approach for that. You give the nyroModal class, as well as `href="#hiddendivid",` the plugin will pull the html from that container. Otherwise it is `content: '<span>inline html</span>'`

Comment: I figured it out. I used the content call. Thanks!

Comment: **DIV** `<div class="myclass" id="hiddendivid">Content</div>` **A** `<a class="nyroModal" href="#hiddendivid">click me</div>`